# How to check if snapshot restore operation has finished

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After failing over a block volume, I fired a restore operation on the replica (restoreFromSnapshot). The API came back in about 2 seconds with return value as True.

I immediately fired an API to failback to the original volume, and got the following error

SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Network_Storage_BlockingOperationInProgress): A Snapshot Restoration is currently in progress on volume IBM02SEL328078-363. During this process, the requested operation (Immediate Failback from Replica Volume) cannot be completed until the process is finished.

So that tells me that even if restoreFromSnapshot() returns success, the actual restore operation might still be in progress.

So what is the way to check the current status of restore operation, and how to determine that it completed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an action over a Sofltayer's resource a transaction is created (almost in all the cases), and you cannot preform new actions over the resource until the transaction is completed. So the way to know if you restore operation is completed is verifying that no-transaction is running, for that propuse you can [use the SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getActiveTransactions](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getActiveTransactions) method:

RESTful e.g.

```
GET https://$USERID:$APIIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$storageID/getActiveTransactions.json

Note replace: $USERID $APIIKEY and $storageID
```

The method will return the transactions running in the storage in case that the method returns empty result the transaction is over.

But there is drawback with this approach, sometimes the transaction takes some time to be created so you need to request the API repeatly until you see the transaction, and in other cases the transaction is executed so quickly that you will never see the transaction, so your code need to handle that practically if you do not see the transaction in a few minutes is likely that this has been completed very fast so you can launch another action over the storage.